# Equivalent formulations of analytic/ $\omega$-suslin sets (in Baire Space)

Tags: set-theory, recursion, computability, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I'm aware that there are more general formulations of these concepts, but I'm just starting to learn these and have been looking at them in a very restricted and simple context.

Let $A \subset \omega^{\omega}$.

We say $A$ is *analytic* if there is $B \subseteq \omega^\omega\times \omega^\omega$ Borel such that $A = proj(B)$ ($proj$ being the projection).

We say $A$ is $\omega$-*suslin* if there is a tree $T \subseteq \omega^{<\omega}\times \omega^{<\omega}$ such that $A = proj([T])$ (where $[T]$ is the set of branches of the tree).

We say $A$ is $\sum^1_1(z)$ for some $z \in \omega^\omega$ if there is a computable set $P \subseteq \omega^{<\omega}\times\omega^{<\omega}\times\omega^{<\omega}$ such that $$x \in A \iff \exists y \in \omega^\omega \forall n\in \omega P(x_{\big|n}, y_{\big|n}, z_{\big|n})$$
where the bars indicate function restrictions.
We say $A$ is $\sum^1_1$ if it is $\sum^1_1(z)$ for some $z \in \omega^\omega$.

**Goal: Show these three notions are equivalent, i.e,**

$A$ is analytic $\iff$ $A$ is $\omega$-*suslin* $\iff$ $A$ is $\sum^1_1$

$\omega$-suslin $\implies$ analytic is trivial.

I'm struggling with analytic $\implies$ $\omega$-suslin.My guess is to notice that the topology on $\omega^\omega \times \omega^\omega$ has a base of countable clopen sets. This implies that every Borel set is clopen (I think? that seems way too strong), and closed sets correspond to trees, which would solve the issue. However, this seems too easy; I'm pretty sure I'm missing a lot here.

As for $\omega$-suslin $\iff$ $\sum^1_1$, I'm completely lost. I'm garbage at recursion theory to begin with, and I'm not at all comfortable with the concepts being used here. I appreciate all the help I could get; I would especially appreciate being pointed to a book or a set of notes that deals with $\sum^1_1$ and the projective hierarchy more slowly and help me understand where to start at least.

Comment: "This implies that every Borel set is clopen" why would it? This is very false, think about what happens in simpler zero dimensional Polish spaces such as $\omega^\omega$ or the Cantor set, you should be able to explicitely write down a Borel set which is not clopen. (in fact the first $\omega_1$ levels of the Borel hierarchy on a Polish space are all distinct but that's not needed at all here)

Comment: Yeah you're right I was looking around for hints and saw a few remarks here and there about "turning borel sets into clopen sets" (like in Kechris for example) so I thought I would give it a try. Never mind that then I guess. How do you suggest I go about proving that direction?

Comment: You correctly remarked that closed sets correspond to trees, so to go from 2 to 1 you can show that the $B$ in 1 can actually be chosen to be closed instead of simply Borel. In order to do so let $S$ denote the class of sets in $\omega^\omega$ that are the projection of a closed set in $\omega^\omega\times\omega^\omega$. Clearly $S$ contains all closed sets, so if we show that $S$ is closed under countable intersections and unions we are done (open sets are $F_\sigma$ and having both union and intersections gives complements so $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra)

Comment: In order to show this closure use the fact that $\mathcal N=\omega^\omega$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal N^\omega$ (this is similar to the trick used to build $\mathcal N$-universal sets for $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\xi(\omega^\omega)$ if you are familiar with that construction) (I'm writing long comments instead of an answer because I have no idea about 2 iff 3, I don't know anything about the computability/recursion theory side of things)

Comment: Thanks for the help! If you don't mind however, I don't see how to leverage the homemorphism you described to show closure of S.

Comment: Actually I was going for an overly complicated route yesterday, here is a simpler approach. Let $A,B$ be as in 1 and let $f\colon\omega^\omega\to B$ be a continuous surjection. Then $\pi\circ f$ is a continuous surjection of $\omega^\omega$ onto $A$, so its graph is a closed subset of $\omega^\omega\times\omega^\omega$ whose projection is $A$

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf half of it yeah. I'm still unsure about analytic implying suslin however.

Comment: Hi, the above is an auto-generated message. Perhaps @AlessandroCodenotti wants to answer that part here (since the computable part is already done in the linked question). Perhaps then you should delete the latter.

Otherwise, I'll streamline his comments into a proper answer later.

Comment: What you **should not do** is to multiplicate an already posed question, I've just seen that you reposted the other part as well.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the first part of the question, namely the equivalence of 1 and 2, since the second half was already answered elsewhere.

As you correctly remarked there is a correspondence between closed subsets of $\omega^\omega$ and pruned trees, giving by taking branches, so to obtain that 1 implies 2 it is enough to show that a set $A\subseteq\omega^\omega$ is analytic if and only if there is a closed $F\subseteq\omega^\omega\times\omega^\omega$ such that $A=\mathrm{proj}(F)$.

In order to do so let $A,B$ be as in 1, so that $B\subseteq\omega^\omega\times\omega^\omega$ is a Borel set such that $A=\mathrm{proj}(B)$. Let $f\colon\omega^\omega\to B$ be a continuous surjection, so that $\mathrm{proj}\circ f$ is a continuous map $\omega^\omega\to\omega^\omega$ with range $A$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\mathrm{graph}(f)\subseteq\omega^\omega\times\omega^\omega$ is closed, and $A=\mathrm{proj}(\mathrm{graph}(f))$, so that $A$ is the projection of a closed subset of $\omega^\omega\times\omega^\omega$.

The only missing ingredient is the existence of such an $f$, but this follows from the fact that every Polish space is a continuous image of $\omega^\omega$ plus the fact that if $C$ is a Borel set in the Polish space $X$, then there is a finer Polish topology on $X$ in which $C$ is clopen, hence Polish itself, and of course a continuous map remains continuous when weakening the topology of the codomain. Both of those facts are proved in Kechris or other descriptive set theory textbooks.